# G-SHEET lookup with multiple criteria horizontal and vertical

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, match, vlookup, textjoin

If you could help me finding a formula that would solve my problem that I've been searching for a solution a few days now

So in my "feuil 1" I have what I'm searching for according to multiple values
-the aircraft number
-data 1
-cell number
-exit date (the value that I'm looking for)
[image: like the image below]

And in another sheet "LH Synthèse" (the database) I have the aircraft number and data 1 in the same row and the cell number that will give me the exit date according to a specific aircraft and data 1 is the column value
[image: my data base]
What I want to do with this spreadsheet is to have a formula that is going to give me the exit date (present in the sheet "LH Synthèse") according to the values that are in the column A, B, C in the sheet "feuil 1"

The link of the spreadsheet in case my description isn't clear enough
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W4jVDT4wiui5h7i9Sx9rptyLnExhQvn9ICEDTFyat0E/edit?usp=drivesdk

Thanks for your help in advance

What I tried:

Index and match function
Filter function
Vlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2; SPLIT(FLATTEN('LH Synthèse '!A3:A100&'LH Synthèse '!B3:B100&'LH Synthèse '!C2:K2&"×"&'LH Synthèse '!C3:K100); "×"); 2; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: The function is working well but when changing the format to change the numbers into date xx/xx/xxxx the date doesn't match with my data base do you have any solution please

Comment: @abdelibnou try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQWrn.png